# How to get the right context for single product using Timber and WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, timber

I have been using Timber whilst building my latest Woocommerce project. It has all been working great but I have one problem I can't figure out: the context on the single product page is not right. On the single product page I have related products and the context of the last product in the loop is used as the context for the current single product.

There is only limited docs available regarding using Timber and Woocommerce. Though I have tried all of them, it doesn't seem to solve the problems.

```php
function timber_set_product($post)
{
    global $product;

    if (is_woocommerce() || is_search() || is_front_page()) {
        $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I have the same setup as https://github.com/timber/timber/blob/master/docs/guides/woocommerce.md but it's not working correctly for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Integrating WooCommerce with Timber can be a bit complicated but it works fine once you know a few tricks.

The main issue comes when you want to override WooCommerce as you then have to do it in the classic Wordpress way, in a "/woocommerce" folder in your theme where you copy the files from the plugin you want t override and not in the Timber way separating concerns in PHP and TWIG files. It's not needed here though.

A way we're doing it to get the product context and related products is to set the product in woocommerce.php :

```
$context = Timber::get_context();

if (is_singular('product')) {

    $context['page']    = Timber::get_post();
    $product            = get_product( $context['page']->id );
    $context['product'] = $product;

    $args = array(
        'post_type'            => 'product',
        'posts_per_page'       => -1,
        'orderby'              => 'DESC',
        'post__in'             => $product->get_related(),
        'post__not_in'         => array( $product->id )
    ) ;
    $context['related'] = Timber::get_posts( $args );

    Timber::render('woo/single-product.twig', $context);

}
```

Comment: But how would you do this for /checkout? Since checkout does not go through woocommerce.php like single product or product category.